# Connecting to soap web service via https (authentication by client certificate) using javascript

Tags: javascript, ssl, soap, client-certificates

I must connect from the client machine to soap web service by https-connection. And client authenticate by x509 certificate.

Is it possible? What lib or framework solve that problem?

Comment: Is this in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

How about using this: https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap or this: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/javascript-clients.html

Comment: Can JQuery.soap connect via https using Client Certificate X509? How can i do this? i didn't find that in official manual.

Does Apache CXF Javascript clients works with IIS web server?

Comment: client certificate should be a browser thing... see this example http://www.garex.net/apache/